# Sass - Check which kind of value a variable has

Tags: variables, if-statement, sass

Suppose i have a variable:

```
$var: 5px;
```

but somewhere in code its value have changed in to possible **color**, **number**, **em**, **rm** etc.

Is there any function to detect which type of value it has?

i.e

```
@if is-color($var) { //do something }
```

I know there is no is-color function in sass but are there other methods to do this or function?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the Sass documentation:

> type_of($value)
>
> Returns the type of a value.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> type-of(100px)  => number
> type-of(asdf)   => string
> type-of("asdf") => string
> type-of(true)   => bool
> type-of(#fff)   => color
> type-of(blue)   => color
> ```

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#type_of-instance_method

(note that `-` and `_` is interchangeable in Sass functions).

Comment: Also can be list, e.g.: `type-of(10px 10px 0 1rem)  => list`

Comment: @Deerloper Ok, that's nice, but I'm just quoting the documentation.

Comment: yup, I don't say it's bad, just adding more info that, btw, I've just discovered :P

Answer (score 13):

To be a little clearer, here's how you might use type-of:

```
@if type-of($my-variable) == string {
    /* do something */
}
```

In addition to the types shown in the docs, type-of will also return 'map' if passed a SASS map object:

```
$font-sizes: (
    small: rem-calc(18px),
    medium: rem-calc(20px),
    large: rem-calc(22px)
);

@if type-of($font-sizes) == map {
    /* do map-related thing */
} @else {
    /* do other thing */
}
```